# How to suppress the certificate check when trying to install anything using apt-cyg?

Tags: cygwin, apt, nano

For Eg:

$ apt-cyg install nano

Installing nano
nano-4.9-1.tar.xz: FAILED
sha512sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
--2022-12-06 13:41:51--  https://cygwin.mirror.constant.com//x86_64/release/nano/nano-4.9-1.tar.xz
Resolving cygwin.mirror.constant.com (cygwin.mirror.constant.com)...
Connecting to cygwin.mirror.constant.com (cygwin.mirror.constant.com)... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘cygwin.mirror.constant.com’ is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of ‘cygwin.mirror.constant.com’ doesn't have a known issuer
nano-4.9-1.tar.xz: FAILED
sha512sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match

I tried **--no-certificate-check** post-fix which is not working with *apt-cyg* actually.

So I am looking how to prevent this error majorly. FYI, I trust that website.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use `apt-cyg` it is not maintained and obsolete.
Use the Cygwin Setup as it fully supports all the compression methods and the latest format of the installation

Comment: Please do not waste our time by reporting problems using `apt-get`. Always use the official installer from the `cygwin.com` site.

Comment: I am using official installer actually and this snap is from cygwin terminal itself. I am completely beginner with this tool so not aware of this.

Comment: gui is not practical as apt-cyg